# Response time of stored procedure called from web api is slow if the service is idle

Tags: web-services, asp.net-web-api, sql-server-2016

I have a web api which executes  a stored procedure which does an R prediction using the sp_execute_external_script. If the service is idle for say 10 min, the response time is 5-10 sec more than when we fire requests continuously to the service.

Comment: Maybe your server doesn't have a lot of memory and the plan is getting flushed from cache.

Comment: how is the service hosted? I'm guessing IIS!

Answer (score 0):

If you're hosting in IIS it's more than likely that IIS is stopping the process after a timeout period. Once this timeout has passed then the site will need to run through it's startup cycle that can take a few seconds, depending on how much you have running before the app is ready.

Try this https://thycotic.force.com/support/s/article/Changing-IIS-to-not-stop-worker-process-in-IIS-7-and-8